# GL Graphics Library won't install

Tags: c++

I am using Eclipse Neon C/C++ and I'm trying to install an external graphics library. I'm using the MinGW Compiler, and the path to the GL folder is in the 'Libraries' section. Why am I still getting an error? How do I install this library?

```
#include <gl/glaux.h>
```

Comment: Unsolvable from the information you've presented in your question. If you have that header file, it's in the path you say it is, and you've added that path to your compiler's settings so it can be found, then the code should work.

Comment: Make sure whatever path you added to your IDE has a gl folder in the folder you added to your path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your project folder, and open includes from there. This will tell you which path to add your header files to.